# How to handle .ics files properly on MAC OSX?

Tags: macos, download, calendar, safari, calendar.app

With [CATSone](http://www.catsone.nl/) we can download .ics files to share calendars between collegues. When I click this download link on Windows, the .ics file is downloaded after which I can import it in my Outlook calendar.

On Mac OSX (El Capitan) however, I cannot get access to the physical .ics file. It is immediately opened in iCal. I can change the "Open with" setting to automatically open it in Outlook 2011, but then when I open it Outlook displays a single appointment, which is not what i want.

How can i download the physical .ics file to my documents, so that I can drag it onto the Outlook calendar? I Do not want to open it automatically with some program, just download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Safari, it may seem like the physical .ICS file is opened immediately in Calendar. In fact, the .ICS file is saved to your Downloads directory then opened by Calendar.

In Chrome, the default behavior may ask you to pick a location to Download the file.

In Firefox, it will ask you how to want to handle .ICS files now and in the future.

You can verify you Downloads directory by going to Safari > Preferences:

[image: Safari > Preferences]

Comment: Thx, sounds good!. We're gonna try this tomorrow and I'll accept the answer if it works.